# move 'tmp' directory not working when uploading image in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

When uploading my image it is saved to `D:\xampp\tmp\phpD0E0.tmp directory`. But I want to save it in `public/uploads/banner`. Anyone please help me. Here is my code:

> BannersController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $requestData = $request->all();


    if ($request->hasFile('banner_image')) {
        foreach($request['banner_image'] as $file){
            $uploadPath = public_path('/uploads/banner');

            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;

            $file->move($uploadPath, $fileName);
            $requestData['banner_image'] = $fileName;
        }
    }

    Banner::create($requestData);
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Banner added!');
    return redirect('Banner/banners');
}
```

Comment: 1$file->move($uploadPath, $fileName);` what is `$file` here ?

Comment: $request['banner_image'] as $file

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan what is your upload path here:  'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads' path in config/filesystems.php

Comment: 'root' => storage_path('app/public')

Comment: @ Jigs Virani changed 
 
'root' => storage_path('app/public') to  'root' => public_path() . '/uploads' but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please revert that path to `'root' => storage_path('app/public')`

and just try with change line:

```
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
```

with this:

```
$fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' .  $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I make demo for this and it's working fine with same code. Please check other possibilities as well. Do let me know if you need any help I ill help you right away.